# limit of functions $f(x)>g(x)$, what can we conclude about their limits

Tags: limits

Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions defined on $S$ and $c$ be a cluster point of $S$. Suppose $f(x)\to l_1$ and $g(x)\to l_2$ as $x\to c$. If $f(x)>g(x)$ for any $x\in S\setminus{\{c\}}$,can we conclude $l_1 > l_2$?

I think not and one of the counter examples I can think of is $x^2$ and $2x^2$, $c=0$?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, taking limits turns strict inequalities to non-strict

Comment: Please, learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your questions will be better received in this site if you show more effort writing them.

Comment: Yes, your counterexample is right.